# AAD B2C "The application with identifier 'ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework' was not found."

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In following this tutorial...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#test-the-custom-policy

I've reached the part where you can test your user flow. When I try the flow to signin I gives the following error after clicking the signin button...

"The application with identifier 'ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework' was not found."

The application is definitely registered in Azure under my tenent. I've also started over and followed this tutorial multiple times to make sure I was doing it correctly. Still no luck.

Has anybody had a similar experience or knows what the problem is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't [add application IDs to the custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy).

Notice the step 3:

> Replace both instances of `ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId` with
>   the application ID of the `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` application
>   that you created earlier.

You can get the application ID of the `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` application from [Register the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#register-the-proxyidentityexperienceframework-application).

Comment: Stupidly I was adding the name instead of the ID. I've added the ID and now it works.  Thanks for pointing out my error!